# jquery windows widthcalculation

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, css, navbar

I have a navbar which gave him a "nav-oferta24" class and I need you if this is in "width > 992" put a class navbar-inverse but if not then place the navbar-default

My code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse nav-oferta24">
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">                                 
                <li><a href="#" class="no-margin">¿Qué es la oferta del día?</a></li>               
            </ul>

            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li class="no-margin no-padding">
                    <a href="#" class="no-margin">
                        <span class="m-r-5">
                            <i class="pg-shopping_cart bg-icon-oferta24h"></i>
                        </span>
                        2 Producto(s)<b><span class="text-naranja m-l-10">56,99€</span></b>
                    </a>
                 </li>
            </ul>

            <ul class="nav navbar-nav center-nav">
                <li class="b-r no-margin no-padding"><a href="#" class="no-margin">Atencion al cliente</a></li>
                <li class="b-r no-margin no-padding"><a href="#" class="no-margin">902 00 55 55</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="no-margin">Contáctanos</a></li>
            </ul>


        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't really see the javascript/jquery code. Anyway, here's how I calculate window height and width:

```
var scw = document.documentElement.clientWidth; // This is screen Width
var sch = document.documentElement.clientHeight;  // this is screen Height
```

https://jsfiddle.net/cxaLgg9z/

the jsfiddle.net emulates the screen, so it won't show your real screen height and width, but the window which it works with :) So try running it on your computer - it will show real W and H.

Comment: I hope this is good start for calculating the other width and heights for other elements?...

Answer (score 0):

Using jquery, you can do this:

```
$().ready(function() {
    if ($('.nav-oferta24').width() > 992) {
         $('.nav-oferta24').addClass('navbar-inverse');
    } else {
         $('.nav-oferta24').addClass('navbar-default');
    }
});
```

This can obviously be cleaned up. But that'll accomplish what you want.

[Heres](http://jsfiddle.net/ybg6anpe/) a working fiddle